# Is it possible to get Visual Studio or Resharper to highlight enum's with a different color?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

I think code would be more readable if it highlighted enums properties with a different color to class properties.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For VS2010 / VS2013 / VS2015 / VS2017 / VS2019:

1. Tools->Options->Environment->Fonts and Colors:
2. Show Settings For Text Editor
3. Display Items: User Types (Enums)
4. Change Item Foreground

Answer (score 4):

You have to enable "Color identifiers" in `ReSharper -> Options -> Code Inspection -> Settings`.

Then you can define the forground/background colors for Enum identifiers in `Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors` (select "ReSharper Enum Identifier" in the "Display items" list.

Note: this is for VS 2010 / ReSharper 6.1.

Comment: This does work, but it tends to muck up my dark theme that I have. Tools->Options->Environment->Fonts and Colors: Display Items: User Types (Enums) seems to be the easiest way to do this.

Comment: I somehow have reshaper playing nice with my dark theme w/ enum color, but that may have changed in 7.1.

Comment: @superlogical That's a bug.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16335896/resharper-color-identifiers-screw-up-with-visual-studio-2012-dark-theme