# ReSharper color identifiers screw up with Visual Studio 2012 dark theme

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, resharper, resharper-7.1

We're experiencing an annoying problem issues with ReSharper's color identifiers feature when Visual Studio 2012 is set to the built-in dark theme.

With ReSharper's color identifiers disabled, the code looks fine:

[image: Code looking fine]

Then, we enable ReSharper's color identifiers:

[image: ReSharper's code inspection settings]

And now the code is completly unreadable:

[image: Some unreadable code]

The curious thing, on a colleague's machine, the same code, with the same Visual Studio and ReSharper settings... looks right:

[image: Some good-looking code]

We tried reinitializing both Visual Studio and ReSharper settings, disabling add-ons and extensions and other voodoos to no avail.

Here are our setups:

- [My add-ins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEMAl.png) - [His add-ins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVvAD.png)
- [My extensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Bs0m.png) - [His extensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmyA9.png)
- [My system informations](https://gist.github.com/kappa7194/5501403) - [His system informations](https://gist.github.com/kappa7194/5501408)

Comment: Have you tried changing the Visual Studio colour scheme to a light one and then back to the dark one?

Comment: @PiersMyers yes, to no avail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By diffing our system information, I noticed three add-ins I had my colleague didn't (JetBrains TeamCity Addin 7.1, VisualSVN 3.0.5 and Git Extensions).

Trying to disable them one by one I found out **the culprit is the add-in for TeamCity**: as soon as I uninstalled it (it's not reported in Visual Studio, and you can't disable it) the color scheme fixed itself.

The funny thing is both ReSharper and the TeamCity add-ins are provided by JetBrains.

Comment: Did you report this issue to JetBrains?

Comment: @DmitryOsinovskiy it seems [they already know](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-23215), I still have to try the latest version of the add-in.

Answer (score 53):

I had this same problem with vs2013 and resharper 8. I was able to fix by following these steps:

> 1. Close all Visual Studio instances
> 2. Open C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio {VS version}\Common7\IDE\Extensions\extensions.configurationchanged file
> 3. Type anything there
> 4. Save the file
> 5. Open VS and check Fonts and Colors in Tools | Options | Environment
>
> source http://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/entries/26859128-ReSharper-Fonts-Colors-settings-do-not-appear-in-Visual-Studio-after-installation

Comment: This worked also for other problems with messed-up colors. Thanks!

Comment: Using Visual Studio 2013 with Resharper 10 and this worked for me!

Comment: Instead of modifying `extensions.configurationchanged` (which requires elevation), you can also run `devenv /updateconfiguration`, an undocumented command which does the same thing

Comment: @IgalTabachnik your comment was hidden and I didn't read it. Else I would have tried instead of doing what's suggested in this answer.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem too in VS2013, unfortunately editing the *configurationchanged* file didn't work for me. However I fixed it by doing the following:

1. deleting the following registry key:

> HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0_Config
>
> Run `devenv /ResetSettings` from VS 2013 admin command prompt

Comment: same here, albireo's fix didnt work, but this one did

Comment: This worked for me as well. I skipped step 1 and executed step 2 from the Start Menu's "Run" panel. Colors....my pretty colors!

Comment: This seems to be a simpler way than the others although I had to rearrange all settings, such as locations of windows in VS

Answer (score 2):

It is a known bug in TeamCity Addin installer. It was fixed in 7.1.5 version. 
Please, look at [related issue in our tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-23215) and [7.1.5 release notes](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/TeamCity+7.1.5+%28build+24400%29+Release+Notes).

Answer (score 2):

I use a custom dark theme in Visual Studio **2010** and probably about 75% of the time when I first open a solution up, ReSharper 7.1.1 does exactly the same thing as in your "unreadable" image.  I mean, the colors look exactly like that.

I have tested this across several computers with no plug-ins except ReSharper, and with various other plug-ins and no matter what, I get this all of the time.  I do not have TeamCity Addin at all and never have.

Anyway, in case anyone is looking for a solution, this fixes it:  Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts & Colors > Ok.  That's it.  Even no changes causes it to refresh and display properly.  I can't prevent it, but this fixes it and is the first step I do pretty much every time I open VS2010.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I use VS2013 and had the same problem. In my case the culprit was the PowerShell Tools extension, after uninstalling it the color scheme went back to a sane state.