# visual studio 2013 highlight the whole word

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, editor

It seems to me that I haven't changed anything in the vs editor configuration, but in the latest days I found this.

When using vs 2013 update 2 rc, I click inside a single word in the cs editor, instead it places the caret inside the word, but the whole word is highlighted with a background color that is not compatible with the dark theme.

If I click on a word and press cancel the word is not deleted, so there is no selection, but simple highlighting of the word.

Do you know where can I find the setting to restore this with correct values?

[image]

Comment: Any plugins? E.g. resharper?

Comment: mine does this if I hold down the ctrl key...Have you tried hitting ctrl a couple of times and then clicking into a word?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are using C#, so I'm posting instructions on how to disable it on the C# editor (It's the same procedure for other languages)

Go to:

**Tools** => **Options** => **Text Editor** => **C#** => **Advanced**

Once on the **Advanced** panel, uncheck the **Highlight references to symbol under cursor** option.

[image]

Comment: done, but nothing changes. I have restarted vs 2013 too, but Always the same problem.
no specific plugin, just 2013 update 2 rc plus some to the additional releases of the build, but I don't think changed editor settings.
The additional problem is that whatevert changed it, added a background color is not compatible with dark theme.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem after installing VS2013 update 2 - in addition, I also [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16335896/resharper-color-identifiers-screw-up-with-visual-studio-2012-dark-theme) that my resharper color settings with dark theme were completely messed up and I couldn't find a way to reset or update it (in VS fonts settings).

Anyway, I finally solved the problem by:

1. deleting the following registry key:

   > HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0_Config
2. Run `devenv /ResetSettings` from VS 2013 admin command prompt