# ReSharper 2016.3 and Solarized Color Theme

Tags: visual-studio-2015, resharper

I have installed the [Visual Studio 2015 Color Theme Editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.VisualStudio2015ColorThemeEditor) and am trying to utilize the [Solarized Theme](https://github.com/lyphtec/solarized) using ReSharper 2016.3.

However, they do not seem to be playing nicely with each other.  Here is a screenshot of what I see with ReSharper **enabled**:

[image: ReSharper enabled]

Here is the same file with ReSharper **disabled**:

[image: ReSharper disabled]

Is there a consideration I am overlooking here?  I tried [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19820599/3602057) but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

ReSharper comes with it own colorizer which ovrrides some but not all colors. These colors can be configured under **Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors**. All ReSharper related colors start with ReSharper as prefix (e.g. ReSharper Class Idendifier is the color used for class identifiers).

Another option would be to turn off colorization of ReSharper:
**ReSharper -> Options -> Code Inspection -> Settings -> Color identifiers**